# Mono application has garbled text on Linux

Tags: c#, winforms, text, fonts, mono

I have a Mono application with a plain-old Windows Forms form that has a single Label control in the center. On Windows, both in Mono and in Microsoft.Net, the application looks fine:

[image: Screenshot on Windows]

However, on Linux, the text is garbled:

[image: Screenshot on Linux]

I'm not sure what could be causing this issue, so any help would be appreciated. The font is Verdana, and I've checked the X11 font directories to ensure Verdana.ttf is in there.

Edit: I just became aware of the following error on standard error:
[image: Pango Error]

Comment: This is utf not being handled properly.

Comment: @Rob Given that UTF-8 is the default encoding, if it was rendering as ASCII or something it would still look correct, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yea, it's not a UTF-8 encoding problem. The garbled text would not have a 1:1 mapping of characters to glyphs if it were a UTF-8 encoding issue.

Comment: The best way to rule out a font issue is to try other fonts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was in stderr! I needed to generate that pango modules file.

Answer (score 1):

The square glyphs suggest that the proper glyphs aren't being found in the font.

Make sure that your Verdana.ttf is 1) complete and 2) not corrupted.

Comment: Just checked and it is there. However I've added more to the question, based on some new information.